# Why is the spacing above equation larger than that below, when the \belowdisplayskip = \abovedisplayskip?

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, vertical-spacing, belowdisplayskip

Both `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` are set to the default of `10pt plus 2pt minus 5pt`, but I can see that display equations are not centered between paragraphs. What is the reason for this, and how can I center them?

I'm also curious to know why the spacing is designed like this. Is it actually tradition or aesthetically pleasing to not have equations vertically centered between paragraphs?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{d}{I} = -AI\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{equation}
    \ln \frac{A_\mathrm{s}}{A_\mathrm{d}} = \int_L\!\!A\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{equation}
    Z = \sqrt{\rho K}
\end{equation}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: never leave a blank line before displayed equations, you do not have vertical space but rather an empty text line before the equation

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had never heard of that after 15 years of using LaTeX. Thank you!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=never+have+a+blank+line+before :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe this is the day I'll finally try the linter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add `\showoutput` and look at (for example) the last equation starting Z= you see

```
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 10.05556
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x500.484, glue set 485.484fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\abovedisplayshortskip) 0.0 plus 3.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 2.21736
...\hbox(9.78264+2.61745)x272.86868, shifted 227.61531
....\hbox(9.78264+2.61745)x45.25339, display
.....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 Z
```

Which shows you that above the equation is a 1-line paragraph with a line that just contains a paragraph indent and a final parfillskip:

```
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

so it's an all-white paragraph and looks like vertical space, but it does not stretch and it would not be dropped at the top of a page, causing an equation at a page break to start too low.

Never leave a blank line in the source above a displayed equation. Remove that and you get

```
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\abovedisplayskip) 10.0 plus 2.0 minus 5.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 0.27292
...\hbox(9.78264+2.61745)x272.86868, shifted 227.61531
....\hbox(9.78264+2.61745)x45.25339, display
.....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 Z
```

with no parskip and no spurious paragraph.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm}
\showoutput
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{d}{I} = -AI\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
    \ln \frac{A_\mathrm{s}}{A_\mathrm{d}} = \int_L\!\!A\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
    Z = \sqrt{\rho K}
\end{equation}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and teaching me about `\showoutput` as well!